# Query OnSubmit Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, umbraco

I am encountering an error using the query below is the snippet of the code:

```
  $('form[action="/home/service/"]').on("click", (function(event) {
    if ($("#id1").val() == "" && $("#id2").val() == "") {
      alert("Invalid entry");

      event.preventDefault();

    } else {
      $('form[action="home/service/"]').submit();
    }
  });
```

the event.preventDefault(); works as it should however its the submit. I have tried using the .off("click" , function); but this didn't work and was the same issue.

Once the preventDefault() method is fired I am unable to resubmit the form once the issues have been resolved? I have seen a few people encounter this but their fixes didn't resolve my issues.

**UPDATE**
this is what I have now, however I am still receiving the issue, The issue is that it works on the initial on submit however as soon as I try to resubmit with the values it appears that the submit button is locked, has anyone encountered this before? Below is my updated code:

```
//function on 
function checkForm(event)
{
debugger;
 if ($("ID1, ID2" ).val() != "" ){ 

return;  
}

else{
event.preventDefault();  
$("#alerts-row").html("<div class='alert_box red'><p>Please Ensure that you have filled in at least one item number below!</p></div>");

 $('form[action="Form"]').unbind("submit", checkForm);
}
}

 $('form[action="form"]').on("submit", checkForm);
```

Thanks,

Gavey

Comment: Are you sure you want the click handler on the form? Or do you want it on the submit button? You might actually want `.on("submit" ...)`

Comment: This would work i guess: `else { this.submit(); }`. `this`, not `$(this)`. But for sure, you shouldn't bind click event to the form. Instead bind submit event to it or click event to any `:submit` children element. FYI, a form can be submited pressing `return` on form's input element, but an synthetic click event would be fired then on first form's submit element ([w3c spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#implicit-submission)).

Comment: Sorry about that, the one I've been using is the on("submit",function) I was trying the various ways possible, to see if it would resolve the issue, but unfortunately it didn't will try the two new ways of doing it today, and see if we have success. Thanks

Comment: What about using native HTML5 forms with elements using the required attribute? It does the same validation you 're trying to recreate with jQuery. Even dependencies can be created without using jQuery and just using native Javascript and die Constraint Validation API.

Comment: sorry, I also forgot to mention I am currently using UmbracoForms, as a CMS which allows the customisers to create and maintain forms with the GUI, thus why I am trying to use the JQuery add in as a plug in from the backend to do the validation, also as an example of how it could be done. 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try putting it before the if statement

```
$('form[action="/home/service/"]').on("click", (function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ($("#id1").val() == "" && $("#id2").val() == "") {
          alert("Invalid entry");

        } else {
          $('form[action="home/service/"]').submit();
        }
      });
```

Comment: I have now tried this, and this still didn't stop the issue happening: 

The event will run once, as soon as its ran again it doesn't run after that. As you guys have said I have changed to the .on("submit", function)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the proper way would be to use the Submit event. If you do that, then on failure to validate you would preventDefault (as you have done), and on success you wouldn't prevent the default.

There's nothing stopping you having a click event on some element that simply calls form.submit(), but you should probably consider using a <Button> instead that can submit automatically.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue which I was having we used unobtrusive Validation, with the help of some samples we were able to create the or statement and allowed us to post the correct validation on the form.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Register new validation adapter
    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool('minimumselect');

    // Add validator to controls
    $input = $("#Input1");
    $input.attr('data-val', 'true');
    $input.attr('data-val-minimumselect', 'Please provide either this or Number 2');

    $input2 = $("Input2");
    $input2.attr('data-val', 'true');
    $input2.attr('data-val-minimumselect', 'please provide this or Ref Number 1');

    // Refresh form - needed to pick up new validator
    refreshFormValidators();
});
```

Thanks,

Richard